# SignalR IIS worker process does not released

Tags: c#, iis, signalr, signalr-backplane, worker-process

We have a simple signalr server and client running with the backplane enabled. When I looked in to the IIS worker process I found out in the current requests tab there is always this signalr connect is showing.

[image]

When I connect like 100 clients 100 current requests are shown in the woker process view. Shouldn't these be removed after connecting or is this the expected behavior from the signalr?

Comment: Why would they be removed? The very purpose of SignalR is to keep the connections alive to do push over HTTP

Comment: So if I connect 1000 clients, 1000 requests will be executing all the time?

Comment: That's the point, yes

Comment: We have the same issue here and have a growing number of connections that keeps building over time. If we have 100+ clients ok fine we expect to see 100+ threads - but these only increase over time so not sure why they stay open for such long periods of time.

Comment: This doesnt feel right at all.  I hope its fine.

Answer (score 4):

The threads will close or get reused by new clients, its basically a thread pool, you shouldn't need to worry about it. The only time you need worry about how many threads are open is if you only have limited cpu resources, and a low open thread limit set.

Comment: Please cite a source

Comment: This might not be relevant now, but all of the singalR documentation at the time and its likely still the same, its the nature of the technology.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr